# Conditional probability for Bayse rule.

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

So I have the following problem. There are 300 million people and 2 million of them are green. Say there are 10 people who are terrorists. 9 out of 10 of these terrorists are green.

What is the probability that a random selected green person is a terrorist?

My reasoning:

$P(Green|Terrorist)=9/10$
$P(green)=2/300$
$P(notgreen)=298/300$
$P(not green|Terrorist)=1/10$

So I have almost everything, except $P(green| not terrorist)$. I am not sure how to find this... I was thinking that perhaps it is (2 million-9)/(300 million-10) is this correct? My book states otherwise, it claims it is 2/300 ...

I would appreciate any help

Comment: The question is not clear "What is the probability that a random selected green person is a terrorist?".  This suggests that we are picking someone randomly from the green people.  Did you mean  "What is the probability that a random selected person is a green terrorist?"

Comment: @NazimJ No, I am looking for $P(terrorist|green)$

Comment: Edited to clear confusion

Comment: Did you give a try assuming that there are $300$ million innocent people $+$ $10$ terrorists?

Comment: The 10 terrorists must be in the 300 figure. 300 is population not innocent

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
0 & terrorist & no terrorist & total \\ \hline
green & 9& 1.999.991&2.000.000 \\ \hline
nogreen &1&297.999.999& 298.000.000\\ \hline
total &10&299.999.990&300.000.000 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Does this table help?